# MPI: Printing logs per Node

Tags: mpi, distributed-computing, openmpi

MPI doesn't support printing logs in an orderly fashion. Is there a way to get logs printed per node? 
Much granular way is to use the `--output-filename` with openmpi which writes out stdout, stderr to files in the node per process i.e., if I have a mpi job running on 2 nodes with 2 processes on each node I can see:

```
Node1:
rank.0/stdout, rank.0/stderr
rank.1/stdout, rank.1/stderr
Node2:
rank.2/stdout, rank.2/stderr
rank.3/stdout, rank.3/stderr
```

How can I merge these files on the fly and write to a single file (or stdout on that node)? 
Ideally I want to merge all the logs on node1 to a log and merge all the logs on node2 to another log on node2. 
P.S: I am working on python3

Answer (score 0):

You can

1. merge the files afterward with a simple shell script
2. use an `MPI_Gather` on the log strings and write them out from the root process.

Other attempts to synchronize the writing inside MPI will likely not work.

Comment: Thanks for your comment Victor. I am looking for an option to do it on the fly rather than after the process. Would it be possible to use MPI_Gather on the stdout/stderr so that I can gather stdout and stderr from rank 0, 1 on Node 1 an rank 2,3 on Node 2 ?

Answer (score 0):

Some implementations allow a "prepend rank" argument to `mpiexec`.  For example, with MPICH I can do `mpiexec -np 4 -l -prepend-rank` and every line gets prefixed with `[N]`  where N is the rank.

If you are using these logs for another step in your workflow, you might want to look at MPI-IO options, and coordinate writing the logs to one file. (Be aware that MPI-IO and text files can be a challenge .  It is a lot easier to reason about MPI-IO behavior with binary data).

Comment: I am using mpirun and it has the option of using --tag-output which prepends the rank number to the start of the log line.  I have to deal with text files only and I am looking for a way to write them to a respective nodes on the fly